# How can I store JSON in Drone and write it to a file without it getting malformed?

Tags: json, base64, drone.io, cloud-sql-proxy

Here's the context of what I'm trying to do.
I would like have a Drone step to run database migrations against a Google Cloud SQL Postgres instance.
I need to use [Cloud SQL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/sql-proxy) in order to access the database. Cloud SQL Proxy requires you provide a credential file to the proxy.

The problem I'm having is that when I try to `echo` or `printf` the environment variable to a file (as suggested [here](https://discourse.drone.io/t/trouble-with-writing-secret-to-json-gcloud-auth/987)) the JSON comes out malformed.

Note: I've tried adding the JSON via Drone GUI and Drone CLI.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I found to this problem is to simply base64 encode the JSON before putting it into Drone.

Decode the base64 when you need it in your step.

Example commands:

Encode: `base64 data.txt > data.b64`

Decode: `echo $CREDS_B64 | base64 --decode > sql-deploy-creds.json`